# Size windows form in inches

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I need to create a form that will be printed. The dimensions will be 4 inches by 4 inches. I only see pixels as the unit when referring to the dimensions of a form. Is there a way to change this to inches? If not, is there a clean conversion from pixels to inches?

Comment: For your screen, it's Pixels Per Inch (PPI) * 4, and PPI depends on your screen resolution. For the printer, it's the same using your printer's DPI instead of PPI, and that DPI again depends on your printer's configured resolution.

Comment: This relies on using a `PrintDocument`, but you can request the printer's DPI with [`PageSettings.PrinterResolution`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.pagesettings.printerresolution%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).